# English Language requirments for Masters in Italy?

Tags: italy

Obiviously it may differ from university to university but i am about talking about general case which is applicable to majority

IELTS and related certificates are necessary or English Language Proficiency certificate from previous university(Bachelor Degree University) of student also acceptable?

Comment: Why would you need any English Language requirement in Italy?

Comment: @Buffy - many European universities are teaching in English these days.

Comment: @JonCuster, hmmm, serves 'em right for making us learn French, German, and maybe Russian in grad school. HA!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak in general, but for the MSc course I teach in (in English) no certifications are mandatory; it is sufficient to submit a written declaration on penalty of perjury (*autodichiarazione*) that you have at least a B2 level ([source](https://didattica.di.unipi.it/en/master-programme-in-computer-science/english-b2-certification/)).

I imagine it is going to be the same in many other universities, since this kind of declaration is regulated by law in Italy; but I have no direct experience.

Comment: So, basically, if you can’t keep up with the English instruction it is on the student. Seems reasonable.